# Concurrent Insert and Update postgres

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, concurrency

Is there a way to solve a problem when you receive a concurrent insert and update for a same field over a  multi-threaded environment.

Example

Thread 1

```
BEGIN 
insert into users (name,age) values('spiderman',27)
COMMIT
```

Thread 2

```
BEGIN
 update into users set age = 26 where name='spiderman';
COMMIT
```

Most of the time update(transaction) is unaware of the insert happening hence it throws and error.

What I see over a here is classical example of race conditions and one way to avoid race conditions is by using effecting locks.

How to apply locks(record) on a record that don't exist in DB yet.

In the above example for insert statement so that Update knows that record is not in DB yet.

Comment: in a web environment, use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control (see the @Version annotation in JPA)

Answer (score -1):

A lock-based solution would be very hard, and probably not worth the trouble. You'd have to find a way to create a set of data with all possible 'name' fields, then create an advisory lock system around that data. It would likely be error-prone, as well.

If, however, the issue is really ensuring that the `UPDATE` won't run until after the `INSERT`, there are easier solutions.

Specifically, what comes to mind is something like:

```
BEGIN;
  SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE name = 'spiderman';
  -- on the application side, check to see what the result is
  -- if it's 0, ROLLBACK
  -- if it's >0:
  UPDATE users SET age = 26 WHERE name = 'spiderman';
COMMIT;
```

If you end up rolling back, you come back and try again later, whether that means something simple like `sleep` for 10 seconds and re-try, or something more complicated like putting the work item back into the queue and continuing with a different piece of work.

If you're concerned about updates happening between the `SELECT` and `UPDATE`, you can `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, which will lock the selected rows until your transaction is completed.

Comment: We normally dont have such situation so introducing sleep would affect almost all insert. I cant do select on update since the concurrent operation happening over here is insert and update. Select is not a part of query plan.

Comment: One way i can think of is set the transaction isolation level to diry uncommitted what do you have to say about that ?

Comment: What version of postgresql are you using? If it's 9.5, then there's now an "upsert" capability, which can work similarly to SETNX. The syntax is something like this:

    `INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('spiderman', 26) ON CONFLICT (name) DO UPDATE SET age = 26;`

Would that do what you need?

Comment: i was under the impression `upsert` hold true for concurrent `insert` atleast that is what i understood when i read it before poasting the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your most recent comment.

`SETNX` is confusing things, I think -- that will set a value *only if* the key doesn't already exist. If it does exist, then it will do nothing.

If you `SETNX foo 27`, and then `SETNX foo 26`, the value of "foo" will be 27, because it existed. Is this the behavior that you want? Because that seems different from what you were describing in your original post.

What I originally thought you wanted was for both threads to successfully make their changes to the database. I've offered a couple of ways to do that. Is that what you need?

Comment: sorry for the confusion what I was trying to convey over here `upsert` can be done since it works(as per my understanding) on concurrent inserts (not insert and update for same selector). Since there is no `select` hence pessimistic locking could not be achieved as well i.e `select for update`. I can't set the DB isolation level to uncommitted since (where transactions can read the state of other transactions). Since I'm not proficient with DB and it locking mechanism the only possible scenario I can think of is using a application locks like setnx. Hence I was addressing that with setnx.

Comment: So I you can help me understand how to achieve that based on DB locking that would be really good for me.

Comment: `like putting the work item back into the queue and continuing with a different piece of work.` we are currently exploring this btw